# Put correct answer in the question or edit the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, accepted-answer

Let's say I have a problem (this is quite common) and ask on one of the Stack sites. There are a few answers, but none of them are really great. Eventually, after some back and forth in the comment section of one of the answers the question gets answered (Let's say a linked blog post did the trick).

I accept the answer since it clearly is the best one and even if it didn't resolve my issue directly, it clearly helped me to do so. But now I know how this is done right (putting all this information together) and I'd like to share this knowledge. What should I do? Here are the options that come to my mind:

- Edit the accepted answer. But the difference might be that big that it would be more a rewrite than an improvement of the answer. I don't like editing other people's stuff in such an invasive way. If the original answer is close enough, I usually do this though.
- Put the thing that worked for into the question. I've seen this now and then and even if it's not great, I could live with it.
- Add an own answer with my solution. The problem here is that it might get lost and not get the attention it deserves. I could link it from the question or the comments though.
- Add my own answer and accept it. This resolves the visibility issue, but it kind of feels like stealing reputation from the person that did the original answering work.

Comment: Encourage the one who helped you to post an answer of their own.

Comment: "Let's say a linked blog post did the trick" yuk. Answers should answer the question you asked as you state them. If the problem took some back and forth to flesh out you need to edit the question to make sure all the new information is included *in the question*.

Comment: Self accepts don't actually "solve" a visibility problem as they aren't sorted ahead of higher-scoring answers.

Comment: It does partially solve the problem, because it has a checkmark. You could also edit into the question "see my answer for how I solved it".

Comment: Posting a better answer than someone else isn't stealing reputation from them.  It's reputation *earned*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your answer is different to the other answer(s) you should add your own answer and accept it. The only drawback to this is that accepts of self answers don't pin the answer to the question.

If you wish to reward the previously accepted answer then award it a bounty. This will indicate that it was more helpful than the other answers - even if the votes don't reflect that.

If your answer is only a minor change to the accepted answer then perhaps an edit is acceptable, but it would have to be a really minor change. The other alternative is to leave a comment addressing the change and hope that the author updates their answer (thanks [iDebug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306467/put-correct-answer-in-the-question-or-edit-the-accepted-answer/306468#comment996307_306468)).

You certainly shouldn't edit the answer into the question.

Comment: Leave a comment under the answer if your addition isn't trivial. The author of the answer can decide whether to integrate into his answer.